# Is having both MS Access 2003 and 2007 on the same computer possible?

Tags: microsoft-access

I have Microsoft Office 2003 first in my computer and since we are on the migration stage to Microsoft Access 2007, I also installed the Microsoft Access 2007 in the same computer. Now I have the 2003 and 2007 in my PC. Do you think it will cause any problem if I do the migration, that I have the two version of the Access in the computer?

---

Additional Question:

I'm just wondering why I'm getting the below window every time I open the Microsoft Access 2003 Microsoft Access 2007. It's really strange. Before I was able to open it after I install the Office 2007 after 3 days it just started this strange thing. I don't have any clue.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Here's Microsoft's answer to your question](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928091/)

> You can install and use more than one
>   version of Microsoft Office on a
>   single computer. For example, you can
>   install and use both Microsoft 2007
>   Office suites and programs and
>   Microsoft Office 2003 on the same
>   computer. However, we do not recommend
>   this.
>
> Note Microsoft does not support using
>   multiple versions of Microsoft Office
>   on versions of Microsoft Windows that
>   have Terminal Services enabled. If you
>   want to run multiple versions of
>   Office, disable Terminal Services.

Comment: thanks for the link Keith. I was just wondering because now I'm getting this window every time I start ms access 2003 or ms access 2007. It always starts to configure something which I really don't know. Any idea what it is? You can try to check it here:
http://de.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2vvrpn8&s=4

Answer (score 1):

The blog post [Installing Office 2003 and Office 2007 on the same system](http://uksbsguy.com/blogs/doverton/archive/2007/05/09/installing-office-2003-and-office-2007-on-the-same-system.aspx) explains how to get Office 2003 files to open with 2003 and Office 2007 files to open with 2007.

Plus you can get rid of the install dialog box. Access is a bit tricky though.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't cause any problems. So far on our dev machines, both Access 2003 and 2007 co-exists as though they are separate applications, and work quite independently of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Some Office programs of differing versions can co-exist without problems, like PowerPoint, while others will only co-exist with difficulty, like Access and Word.

This means that both versions install separately quite well. The problem arises when you start a version which is not the "current" one. In this case you'll get an Office installation dialog that lasts forever and that will establish the new version as the "current". This dialog is driving me crazy, too, so I try not to change versions too much.

I've not found any solution to this behavior called "co-existence" by Microsoft.
There are only two solutions:

1. Wait for the installation to finish
2. Use a virtual machine for one of the versions.

Maybe someone else can suggest another solution, but I don't know of any.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can have multiple versions of MS Office on the same PC. Its better if the older version is installed first & then the newer version. (Cause newer version is aware of the old version.)

The answer to your question:

> I'm just wondering why I'm getting
>   this window every time I open the ms
>   access 2003 or ms access 2007. It's
>   really strange.
>   There is something missing or something has changed on the PC with regards to Office after Windows Installer (Which is used by Microsoft to install Office) installed Office.

Basically Windows Installer Service is trying to restore some missing feature or setting & since you have two different versions of Office, each is trying to set (mostly a setting) as per its internal database. See this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/40124/cant-delete-folder-from-start-menu/40175#40175).

There is nothing much you can do about it (As far as I feel.) I suggest you let the installer complete next time it tries to reset the setting. Don't cancel. Then see if the same thing happens again.

Comment: hi, that's what I also do, I just let it complete and the ms access will open at the end. and if I close my database and open a new database, it will still do the same.

Comment: "Its better if the older version is installed first & then the newer version"  I have deliberately installed MS Access 97, 2000, 2002, 2003 and 2007 on several different machines in random order.  So you don't need to install in chronological sequence.